# How to access array/cell element in a uniform way

Tags: matlab

In MATLAB, the i-th element of an array is accessed by a(i), while the i-th element of a cell is accessed by a{i}. So my code has to do different things in terms of whether a is a cell or not.

Is there a better way to do it? so we can access the i-th element in a 'same'? way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the *i*th element of any array in the same way, `a(i)`, and the behaviour is completely uniform: you get back an object of the same class as `a`.   So if `a` is a 5x5 `double` array, `a(i)` is a 1x1 double.   Similarly, if `a` is a cell array,  then `a(i)` is a 1x1 cell.   So far, so logical and consistent.

Now, if you want to look *inside* a cell, you use `a{i}` but that is a fundamentally different operation.  Your question seems to imply that it would be "better" if these two fundamentally different operations had the same syntax. It wouldn't: if this were the case, then the ability to slice a cell array into arbitrary shapes (including 1x1) would be overshadowed.

But you can always write a custom function. Among the many Matlab workarounds I carry with me everywhere, I have the following pair of functions:

```
function a = ascell(a)
if ~iscell(a), a = {a}; end
```

and

```
function a = uncell(a)
if iscell(a) & numel(a) == 1, a = a{1}; end
```

With `uncell.m` on your path, `b = uncell(a(i));` would give you the *i*th element of `a` with the cell wrapping, if any, stripped off.

It is good to have the call to `uncell` visible in the code because it alerts you (or another maintainer) to the possibility that `a` might legally be a cell *or* a non-cell—this is by no means necessarily true in everybody's coding strategy. Nor will my code necessarily follow the same convention as yours when it comes to interpreting the *meaning* and correct treatment of a cell array where a non-cell was expected, or a non-cell where a cell was expected (and this is another way of explaining why there's no common syntax).  This leads me to the question: if the design of your application is such that `a` can by its nature contain elements with mismatched shapes or types, then why not simply decree that it is always a cell, never a non-cell, and always access the *i*th element as `a{i}`?

Comment: I assume that when all elements are the same, array can work faster than cell. So I use both array and cell. If this assumption is wrong, I agree that that always using cell solves the problem.

Comment: That really depends on the operation you want to perform. You're right that many operations *can* be implemented such that they run much faster on numeric arrays, by "vectorizing" to eliminate loops—but now you're definitely back to having one chunk of code for numeric and another for cells. If the only difference in the two branches of your code is `a(i)`vs `a{i}` I wouldn't expect much of a speed-up. Also I am told that general-purpose matlab loops have been getting (since r2015a) much faster, so vectorizing helps in fewer cases now.